# No resource found that matches the given name (string)

Tags: android, eclipse

In one of my layouts I need a string:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewReso"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:text="@strings/settings_reso" />
```

but Eclipse tells me

```
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@strings/settings_reso')
```

However, here's my `res/values/strings.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Crono</string>

    <string name="wallpaper_description">Fond d\'écran Crono</string>

    <string name="settings_enable_text">Activer l\'écran de veille</string>
    <string name="settings_output_text">Sortie son haut-parleur \?</string>
    <string name="settings_gallery">Galerie</string>
    <string name="settings_reso">Résolution : HD/SD</string>
    <string name= "settings_force">"Forcer la mise à jour des contenus"</string> 
    <string name="settings_time_text">Temps entre les vidéos (s)</string>
    <string name="settings_server_text">Adresse du serveur</string>

</resources>
```

So actually there IS such a resource! Now why isn't it generated my `R` file? Is is because of the French characters?

Comment: Is there any errors in string.xml file?

Comment: There isn't any according to Eclipse, and there isn't any according to a human reading it (right ? It's included in my post, you can read it).

Comment: UPDATE : I sould have used "@string/string_name" rather than "@strings/string_name" (notice the 's'). DUMB !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewReso"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/settings_reso" />
```

Just change `@strings` to `@string` in your layout xml file.

Comment: Yeah we posted at the same time. Thank you. Now the R file won't be generated, but I'll make it another question (and look through a few hundreds of the thousands of similar questions about missing R files).

Comment: Although this answer is correct please try explaining what was the actual error and not only post the solution.

Comment: @harpun thnk you for your suggestion. from next time i always remember this thing.

Comment: @harpun i hope every user think like you so that freshers like me easily understand answers if post any question.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change @strings to @string in your layout xml file!

**android:text="@string/settings_reso"**

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textViewReso"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:text="@string/settings_reso" />
```

Answer (score 2):

The reference keyword for a string is @string and not @strings (notice the 's'). So in my layout it should read :

```
android:text="@string/settings_reso" />
```

and not :

```
android:text="@strings/settings_reso" />
```

Pretty dumb, but pretty invisible.